# Counting Duplicates without aggregation or group_by

Tags: r, dataframe

After scouring the web and StackOverFlow, I can't find a solution. I'm trying to count the number of times an "ID" number shows within the data frame in Column NumIDShowsInCol_1 without aggregation or group-by functions. When done correctly the end result will still possess 100 observations. If aggregation or group-by function is used then the resulting column is <100 and not be merged with the data frame. Below is sample code and an example of the resulting data frame showing the desired result.

```
set.seed(123)
df <- data.frame(ID = sample(1:30, 100, replace = T),
             TotalDays = sample(15:1000, 100, replace = T),
             NumEnroll = sample(1:3, 100, replace = T),
             NumIDShowsInCol_1 = sample(0, 100, replace = T))

Desired Outcome: 

     ID TotalDays NumEnroll NumIDShowsInCol_1
1     5       307         2                 3
2    12       945         1                 4
3    23        85         3                 5
4    19       650         2                 5
5    28       642         2                 3
6    17       191         3                 4
```

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: 1. The example output is just the first rows right, you expect 100 rows? 2. I'm going to add a `set.seed` to your code to make the values reproducible, but you'll need to edit the desired outcome values.

Comment: Thank you for the help. I'll make sure to set seed in the future. The example was to show what I was expecting and cannot produce it. Should I have done something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact you can use `dplyr::group_by` to count `ID` and not lose any observations:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  group_by(ID) %>% 
  mutate(NumIDShowsInCol_1 = n()) %>% 
  ungroup()

# A tibble: 100 x 4
      ID TotalDays NumEnroll NumIDShowsInCol_1
   <int>     <int>     <int>             <int>
 1     5       307         2                 3
 2    12       945         1                 4
 3    23        85         3                 5
 4    19       650         2                 5
 5    28       642         2                 3
 6    17       191         3                 4
 7     2       855         2                 4
 8     6       857         3                 5
 9    19       276         2                 5
10     8       934         2                 3
# ... with 90 more rows
```

Comment: Thank you too! I was searching dplyr. I didn't see there was an ungroup function. This is great. I'll give it a try in the morning.  Would the same go for summing the ids? e.g. 17+17+17?

Comment: It's best to `ungroup` after any grouping operation, otherwise you forget that you grouped and then get unexpected results. But yes, if you group and then mutate a column, you'll get the result of the operation repeated for every member of the group. Only `summarise` aggregates and removes rows.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I tired the example and worked very well. As you can tell I'm learning R via self study. If there are any other useful sites or useful resources I would love to know... have a great night!

Comment: @Nate if you appreciated ppl's solutions maybe up their solutions?

Comment: @xiaodai I Can't due to low reputation. when I get to 15 i'll do it.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use by together with `:=` from the `data.table` package.

```
df <- data.frame(ID = sample(1:30, 100, replace = T),
                 TotalDays = sample(15:1000, 100, replace = T),
                 NumEnroll = sample(1:3, 100, replace = T),
                 NumIDShowsInCol_1 = sample(0, 100, replace = T))


library(data.table)
setDT(df)

df[,NumIDShowsInCol_1 := as.numeric(.N), ID]
df
```

you can improve your example by not pre-generating `NumIDShowsInCol_1` and therefore there is no need to convert `.N` to numerics.

```
df <- data.frame(ID = sample(1:30, 100, replace = T),
                 TotalDays = sample(15:1000, 100, replace = T),
                 NumEnroll = sample(1:3, 100, replace = T))


library(data.table)
setDT(df)

df[,NumIDShowsInCol_1 := .N, ID]
df
```